# Call two function apps asynchronously from a Logic App

Tags: azure, asynchronous, azure-logic-apps

Requirement : Call two function apps as actions of a HTTP Request so that they are executed asynchronously.

Context: I have a logic app, where in I receive a HTTP Request. In the action part of the HTTP Request, I need to call a AI Logging function and a custom function. As they have independent roles and actions, Can I call them asynchronously. If so, can you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have two parallel actions that runs together, independently from each other. In your case, after the request trigger, add an Azure Function action to call the first function. Then, hover on the arrow in between the request and function -> add parallel action -> add another function.